# Error subreport could not be shown

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I have a main report and its sub report, both have one tablix each in them. The sub report has same parameters as the main report, which are passed to the sub report during runtime. 
FY and Month and DepartmentName. 
FY and Month are single valued parameters, DepartmentName is multivalued parameter. 
Main report has one tablix for Finance department and Subreport has the other tablix for Marketing department.

Problem: the sub report works when I choose the following parameters during report runtime. 
FY=2018; Month= Aug and DepartmentName = Marketing

However the sub report throws an error when I change the main report parameter FY from 2018 to 2019.

Now this parameter FY gets its year from a dataset on the Main report, which was where I changed the WHERE clause to have the dataset return 2019 as the input to the FY parameter.

Error: Subreport could not be shown.

Please advise, as I tried everything but nothing worked.

Comment: do you really need a sub-report or you were just used to Crystal Reports?

Comment: My report is more complex, i just simplified it for the ease of explaining the problem.

Comment: you do know what SSRS can render multiple datasets and parameters to pass from one dataset to another right?

Comment: What happens if you run the subreport on it's own and pass in the parameters that are causing it to fail? You need to start by testing the subreport and work backwards. In particular, If yo have 'available values' set in the subreport parameters, make sure that what you are passing in matches, or simply remove the available value from the subreport altogether, especially if the subreport will never be run on its own (this will improve performance too)